# Search-engine: Php get data from anchor-tag

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, anchor

I have this html search here:

```html
      <form action="index.php" method="POST">
      <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search for Friends" name="search_name">
      <input class="submit" type="submit" name="search-submit" value="Search">
      </form>
```

And this php code for the search engine:

```html
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['search-submit'])) {
   $search_name = $_POST['search_name'];
   $aVar = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','socialnetwork');
   $result = mysqli_query($aVar, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username LIKE '%$search_name%'");
   $found = 1;
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $username = $row['username'];
     @$output .= '<h2 class="friends-display"><a href="">'.$username.'</a></h2><hr>'; 
   }
 }

 ?>
```

Now this code is working fine. It allows the user to search for other users. 
 The anchor tag **"friends-display"** shows the result of the code by using the variable `$output`. The `$output` is then echoed later in the aside.

My problem is the following: I want to make an if-statement so when the anchor tag **"friends-display"** is clicked by the user it should show the profile of the username the user has clicked on.

Example: you search for *Mike* and you find this username. Than you click on it and it should show the profile of *Mike*. How can I make this with an anchor tag?

I have tried `if isset()`, but it did not work for me.

Comment: Greetings and welcome to SO.  I cut your long paragraph into multiple.  I understand you are not a native English speaker, but you must break up long explanations a bit to make them more readable.

Comment: @Nic3500 Thank you very much:) I will do it next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the output variable like below

```
....
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    $username = $row['username'];
     @$output .= '<h2 class="friends-display"><a href="profile.php?user='.$username.'">'.$username.'</a></h2><hr>'; 
}
....
```

Create a new file profile.php and add the following basic line.

```
<?php
If(isset($_GET['user']) && !empty($_GET['user'])){
    $username = $_GET['user'];
    // check for username found in database. 
    // if not found exit with error "user not found"
    // else show user profile
}else{
    Die("unothrized access");
}
```

I hope this will guide you to achieve your target.. 
Happy coding :)